# how to give a confirm() two separated excute orders

Tags: javascript, html

I have a

```
           <a href="#" onclick="ConfirmDelete()" class="btn btn-danger my-1 mx-1"> delete </a>

           function ConfirmDelete() {
confirm("delete user");
    }
```

so the problem is that
hello there is a problem when I press cancel it still deletes the user info ( it executes the same order no matter you press cancel or ok )

Comment: There is nothing that would trigger an delete in your code. Where does that happen?

Comment: please show your `confirm` function

Comment: @Einliterflasche [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) is a native function.

Answer (score 2):

confirm returns true/false depending on user input.  So if it returns true, then continue.  If it returns false, do not do anything.

```
function ConfirmDelete() {
    if (confirm("delete user")){
      //do something
    }
}
```